# ng-admin how to connect remote server

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

I am green hand in ng-admin, and the question is:
Is it possible to connect to the remote server to get data? such as.

var admin = nga.application('QDNS Admin')
        .baseApiUrl('http://remote host/');

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The reason is: I just want to put the web server on one host and the data server on another.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In your admin.js file you have to configure your API endpoints like this:

```js
myApp.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider', function (nga) {
    // create an admin application
    var admin = nga.application('Name of your Admin')
      .baseApiUrl('http://localhost:8080/api/');
    //if you have an entity called users

    nga.configure(admin);
}
```

And in your server.js you must have define a route

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In your admin.js file you have to configure your API endpoints like this:

```js
myApp.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider', function (nga) {
    // create an admin application
    var admin = nga.application('Name of your Admin')
      .baseApiUrl('http://localhost:8080/api/');
    //if you have an entity called users
    // the API endpoint for this entity will be 'http://localhost:8080/api/users/
    var user = nga.entity('users').identifier(nga.field('_id'));
        user.listView()
.fields([
 nga.field('username'),
    nga.field('email'),
    nga.field('password'),
    nga.field('lastname'),
    nga.field('firstname'),
    nga.field('created_at'),
    nga.field('updated_at')
    ]);
    admin.addEntity(user);
    nga.configure(admin);
}
```

And in your server.js you must have define a route